# Accessing a value in a multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, json

After decoding my JSON to an array and using [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) on it, I see the following output:

```
Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 197849982
                    [url] => https://somewhere.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/197849982.json
                    [name] => Some User
                    [created_at] => 2012-04-15T00:38:33Z
                    [updated_at] => 2012-06-08T07:53:03Z
                    [time_zone] => Sydney
                    [email] => email@email.com
                    [phone] => 
                    [photo] => 
                    [locale_id] => 1
                    [locale] => en-US
                    [organization_id] => 21520772
                    [role] => admin
                    [verified] => 1
                    [external_id] => 
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [alias] => 
                    [active] => 1
                    [shared] => 
                    [shared_agent] =>
```

There is more output, but I've truncated it.

I need to access the values such as 'id' and 'name' and put them into variables, but I can't figure out how to get to them inside that array. I've tried several ways and get different errors each time.

How can I access the data in this array?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

```
$id = $data['users'][0]['id']
```

I would assume that you are going to have more than one user so i would do something like

```
$users = array();
foreach($data['users'] as $user){
  $users[$user['id']] = $user['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only ever have one user in that result set:

```
$user = $arr['users'][0];

$id = $user['id'];
$name = $user['name'];
```

If you have more and you want to loop through them then:

```
$users = $arr['users'];

foreach($users as $user){
    $id = $user['id'];
    $name = $user['name'];

    // Do something with each user here
}
```